# Missing request header 'client_id' for method parameter of type String

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure-aks, request-headers

While doing a post request to the Spring Boot Rest API it is throwing Servlet Request Binding Exception with error message "Missing request header 'client_id' for method parameter of type String". Even after passing the client_id field in header.

It is happening in only one of our testing env. **where request header is containing "_" underscore in its name.** Same code is working in local.  What could be the issue here. Is it something related to deployment file or code related issue.

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:7087/test' \
--header 'accept: application/json' \
--header 'client_id: test' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "data": "test"
}'




 @PostMapping(path = "/test", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Object pushMsg(@Valid @RequestBody String data, 
            @RequestHeader("client_id") String clientId) {
            return null;
    }
```

Comment: what is the failing terminal? there maybe some know issue if you use such curl syntax in windows powershell, for example.